# add a value section to web page

Tags: javascript, css, html, kendo-ui

I have several radial, and linear gauges for this dashboard I'm building. I would like to be able to print out the value each gauge is reading next to the gauge. Is there any function out there that can do this in HTML or CSS?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Data Metrics</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>

  <body style="background-color: black">

    <table border= 2px>
      <tr>
        <td style="color: White">Overall Risk</td>
        <td style="width: 300px">
          <div id="overall_gauge"></div>
          <script>
            $("#overall_gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Red",
                value: 71.8,
              },

              scale: {
                majorUnit: 10,
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                startAngle: -40,
                endAngle: 220,
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table border="2px">
      <tr>
        <td style="color:white">Security Systems</td>
        <td>
          <div id="1st_gauge"></div>
          <script>
            $("#1st_gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Red",
                value: 92,
              },

              scale: {
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                startAngle: -30,
                endAngle: 210,
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });

          </script>
        </td>
        <td style="color:white">Patching</td>
        <td>
      <div id="2nd_gauge"></div>
      <script>
        $("#2nd_gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
          pointer: {
            color: "Red",
            value: 100,
          },

          scale: {
            majorTicks: {
              color: "white",
            },
            minorUnit: 5,
            minorTicks: {
              color: "white",
            },
            startAngle: -30,
            endAngle: 210,
            max: 100,
            labels: {
              color: "white",
              template: "#= value #%"
            },
            ranges: [
              {
                from: 0,
                to: 20,
                color: "Red"
              }, {
                from: 20,
                to: 40,
                color: "#ff6600"
              },
              {
                from: 40,
                to: 60,
                color: "Orange"
              },
              {
                from: 60,
                to: 80,
                color: "Yellow"
              }
              ,
              {
                from: 80,
                to: 100,
                color: "Green"
              }
            ]
          }
        });

      </script>
        </td>
        <td style="color:white">Congifuration</td>
        <td>
      <div id="3rd_gauge"></div>
      <script>
        $("#3rd_gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
          pointer: {
            color: "Red",
            value: 80,
          },

          scale: {
            majorTicks: {
              color: "white",
            },
            minorUnit: 5,
            minorTicks: {
              color: "white",
            },
            startAngle: -30,
            endAngle: 210,
            max: 100,
            labels: {
              color: "white",
              template: "#= value #%"
            },
            ranges: [
              {
                from: 0,
                to: 20,
                color: "Red"
              }, {
                from: 20,
                to: 40,
                color: "#ff6600"
              },
              {
                from: 40,
                to: 60,
                color: "Orange"
              },
              {
                from: 60,
                to: 80,
                color: "Yellow"
              }
              ,
              {
                from: 80,
                to: 100,
                color: "Green"
              }
            ]
          }
        });

      </script>
        </td>
        <td style="color:white">Network</td>
        <td>
      <div id="4th_gauge"></div>
      <script>
        $("#4th_gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
          pointer: {
            color: "Red",
            value: 60,
          },

          scale: {
            majorTicks: {
              color: "white",
            },
            minorUnit: 5,
            minorTicks: {
              color: "white",
            },
            startAngle: -30,
            endAngle: 210,
            max: 100,
            labels: {
              color: "white",
              template: "#= value #%"
            },
            ranges: [
              {
                from: 0,
                to: 20,
                color: "Red"
              }, {
                from: 20,
                to: 40,
                color: "#ff6600"
              },
              {
                from: 40,
                to: 60,
                color: "Orange"
              },
              {
                from: 60,
                to: 80,
                color: "Yellow"
              }
              ,
              {
                from: 80,
                to: 100,
                color: "Green"
              }
            ]
          }
        });

      </script>
        </td>
        <td style="color:white">Applications</td>
        <td>
      <div id="5th_gauge"></div>
      <script>
        $("#5th_gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
          pointer: {
            color: "Red",
            value: 35,
          },

          scale: {
            majorTicks: {
              color: "white",
            },
            minorUnit: 5,
            minorTicks: {
              color: "white",
            },
            startAngle: -30,
            endAngle: 210,
            max: 100,
            labels: {
              color: "white",
              template: "#= value #%"
            },
            ranges: [
              {
                from: 0,
                to: 20,
                color: "Red"
              }, {
                from: 20,
                to: 40,
                color: "#ff6600"
              },
              {
                from: 40,
                to: 60,
                color: "Orange"
              },
              {
                from: 60,
                to: 80,
                color: "Yellow"
              }
              ,
              {
                from: 80,
                to: 100,
                color: "Green"
              }
            ]
          }
        });

      </script>
          </td>
        <td style="color:white">Awareness</td>
        <td>
      <div id="6th_gauge"></div>
      <script>
        $("#6th_gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
          pointer: {
            color: "Red",
            value: 55,
          },

          scale: {
            majorTicks: {
              color: "white",
            },
            minorUnit: 5,
            minorTicks: {
              color: "white",
            },
            startAngle: -30,
            endAngle: 210,
            max: 100,
            labels: {
              color: "white",
              template: "#= value #%"
            },
            ranges: [
              {
                from: 0,
                to: 20,
                color: "Red"
              }, {
                from: 20,
                to: 40,
                color: "#ff6600"
              },
              {
                from: 40,
                to: 60,
                color: "Orange"
              },
              {
                from: 60,
                to: 80,
                color: "Yellow"
              }
              ,
              {
                from: 80,
                to: 100,
                color: "Green"
              }
            ]
          }
        });

      </script>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border = "2px" align="right">
      <tr>
        <td style="color:yellow">Infrastructure Controls</td>
        <td style="width: 500px;height:250px">
          <div id="linear-gauge11"></div>
          <script>
            $("#linear-gauge11").kendoLinearGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Blue",
                value: 15,
              },
              scale: {
                vertical: false,
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });
          </script>
          <div id="linear-gauge12"></div>
          <script>
            $("#linear-gauge12").kendoLinearGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Blue",
                value: 45,
              },
              scale: {
                vertical: false,
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });
          </script>
          <div id="linear-gauge13"></div>
          <script>
            $("#linear-gauge13").kendoLinearGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Blue",
                value: 35,
              },
              scale: {
                vertical: false,
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="color:yellow">Preventative Controls</td>
        <td><div id="linear-gauge21"></div>
          <script>
            $("#linear-gauge21").kendoLinearGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Blue",
                value: 95,
              },
              scale: {
                vertical: false,
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });
          </script>
          <div id="linear-gauge22"></div>
          <script>
            $("#linear-gauge22").kendoLinearGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Blue",
                value: 75,
              },
              scale: {
                vertical: false,
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });
          </script>
          <div id="linear-gauge23"></div>
          <script>
            $("#linear-gauge23").kendoLinearGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Blue",
                value: 35,
              },
              scale: {
                vertical: false,
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="color:yellow">Detective Controls</td>
        <td><div id="linear-gauge31"></div>
          <script>
            $("#linear-gauge31").kendoLinearGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Blue",
                value: 65,
              },
              scale: {
                vertical: false,
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });
          </script>
          <div id="linear-gauge32"></div>
          <script>
            $("#linear-gauge32").kendoLinearGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Blue",
                value: 30,
              },
              scale: {
                vertical: false,
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });
          </script>
          <div id="linear-gauge33"></div>
          <script>
            $("#linear-gauge33").kendoLinearGauge({
              pointer: {
                color: "Blue",
                value: 10,
              },
              scale: {
                vertical: false,
                majorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                minorUnit: 5,
                minorTicks: {
                  color: "white",
                },
                max: 100,
                labels: {
                  color: "white",
                  template: "#= value #%"
                },
                ranges: [
                  {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 20,
                    color: "Red"
                  }, {
                    from: 20,
                    to: 40,
                    color: "#ff6600"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 40,
                    to: 60,
                    color: "Orange"
                  },
                  {
                    from: 60,
                    to: 80,
                    color: "Yellow"
                  }
                  ,
                  {
                    from: 80,
                    to: 100,
                    color: "Green"
                  }
                ]
              }
            });
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us what you have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your gauges are already JavaScript, with hardcoded values, it wouldn't make much sense to create a pure css solution.

By using jQuery's `.after()` function you can add content to your document right after the selected element.

Here's an example for one gauge (as a bonus I seperated the JS):

```js
jQuery().ready(function() {
    var overallValue = 71.8;
    $("#overall_gauge").kendoRadialGauge({
   pointer: {
  color: "Red",
  value: overallValue,
   },

   scale: {
  majorUnit: 10,
  majorTicks: {
    color: "white",
  },
  minorUnit: 5,
  minorTicks: {
    color: "white",
  },
  startAngle: -40,
  endAngle: 220,
  max: 100,
  labels: {
    color: "white",
    template: "#= value #%"
  },
  ranges: [
    {
   from: 0,
   to: 20,
   color: "Red"
    }, {
   from: 20,
   to: 40,
   color: "#ff6600"
    },
    {
   from: 40,
   to: 60,
   color: "Orange"
    },
    {
   from: 60,
   to: 80,
   color: "Yellow"
    }
    ,
    {
   from: 80,
   to: 100,
   color: "Green"
    }
  ]
   }
 }).closest('td').after('<td>' + overallValue + '</td>');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<table border= 2px>
  <tr>
    <td style="color: White">Overall Risk</td>
    <td style="width: 300px">
      <div id="overall_gauge"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, you might want to use some CSS instead of tables.

Comment: This + a general HTML/CSS/JS separation and clean up. And I think the dashboard itself can be a lot more dynamic, Op is repeating lots of JS...